# Counting 2 instead of 1 value

Tags: mysql

My problem is the column "topic_content" of the table tb_topics only has 1 row topic but COUNT(tt.topic_content) displays 2 instead of 1. What is wrong with this query. All are correct instead of that one.

```
SELECT tc.cat_id, tc.cat_name, tc.cat_description, COUNT(tt.topic_content),  
COUNT(tr.reply_topic), tt.topic_subject, tu.lname, tu.fname, tt.topic_date 
FROM tb_category AS tc 
INNER JOIN tb_replies as tr 
INNER JOIN tb_topics as tt 
INNER JOIN tbl_students as tu 
WHERE tu.studentID = tr.reply_by 
AND tt.topic_cat = tc.cat_id
```

Comment: why don't you use ON in your inner joins to tell mysql on what it should inner join the tables

Comment: Please, provide structure and sample data. From top of my head `INNER JOIN` without `ON` or `USING` is effectively `CROSS JOIN` and that could mess up your result.